# How to make log file password protected in J2EE Application?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, logging, jboss7.x

I have to ensure if a log file hacks or distributed through unauthorized activity, it should be password protected. I am using Jboss AS7. Is there any mechanism through which i make the log file password protected? I didn't find any relevant document on this.

Comment: You should write your own log message encryption and decryption. But Shouldn’t logs are for reading. why any one need them to be protected. You must not log any credentials into logs.

Comment: Seems to me like a strange request, since if someone has access to your application server, you are in more trouble than caring about your JBoss log file...

Comment: My vendor told me that he show similar things with an application.... And he need similar implementation.... It is one of my bad....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default log file is a simple text file sitting in the filesystem. Anybody with read access to the according files will be able to read it.

Anybody who can compromise your logs, can also compromise the entire backend server, so you should perhaps worry about the integrity of your backend system in general.